# Why is ANSI padding enabled by default in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

Can someone explain to me what logic there is to enabling ANSI padding by default in SQL server.

Where the two code snippets below return true

```
if len('       ') = len('') begin
    print 'true'
end
else begin
    print 'false'
end

if '       ' = '' begin
    print 'true'
end
else begin
    print 'false'
end
```

**EDIT:** I do not care about that you can turn it off. Does anyone know why it is on? Is it a database design decision? Is it a database optimisation? What are the positives of this being used? It certainly doesn't make much sense to me - all I see are negatives.

Comment: Well, from the name of it, the logic would be to comply with a standard? ANSI = American National Standards Institute.

Comment: It's just a default setting. You can easily change it, either per database or in single batches / transactions. Same as the default collation being case-insensitive, which some people would argue is a poor choice.

Comment: Note that `SET ANSI_PADDING OFF` is a [deprecated feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) that will not even be allowed in some future version.

Comment: The results in your example do not change under `SET ANSI_PADDING OFF;` `ANSI_PADDING` [Controls the way the column stores values shorter than the defined size of the column, and the way the column stores values that have trailing blanks in char, varchar, binary, and varbinary data.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx)

Comment: Good point @MartinSmith - I've down-voted the question because the behaviour doesn't seem to be related to the setting.  Is there a setting that changes the behaviour of the code in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[To be compliant with the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626/en-us):

> SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2,
>   , General rules #3) on how to compare strings
>   with spaces. The ANSI standard requires padding for the character
>   strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before
>   comparing them. The padding directly affects the semantics of WHERE
>   and HAVING clause predicates and other Transact-SQL string
>   comparisons. For example, Transact-SQL considers the strings 'abc' and
>   'abc ' to be equivalent for most comparison operations.

Answer (score 2):

Testing the behaviour:

```
SELECT SESSIONPROPERTY('ANSI_PADDING') AS [ANSI_PADDING]

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

IF '       ' = '' BEGIN
    PRINT 'TRUE'
END
ELSE BEGIN
    PRINT 'FALSE'
END

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF

IF '       ' = '' BEGIN
    PRINT 'TRUE'
END
ELSE BEGIN
    PRINT 'FALSE'
END

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
```

Output:

```
TRUE
TRUE
```